# Delphi - Copying a record selected on a DBGrid and inserting it into another ADO table

Tags: database, delphi, ado

So I'm trying to copy a certain selected record/ active record from a DBGrid (which is of course connected to an ADO Table via a TDataSource component) into another ADO Table but I'm not sure how to approach this?

The 2 databases involved are exactly the same, they just have different names and purposes.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Kind Regards
PrimeBeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TfrmEntry.Copy(tblSource: TADOTable; tblDest: TADOTable);
var
  i:integer;
begin
    tblDest.Open;
    tblDest.Append;
    tblSource.Open;
    for i := 0 to tblSource.FieldCount -1 do
    begin
        tblDest.Fields[i].AsString := tblSource.Fields[i].AsString;
    end;
    tblDest.Post;
end;
```

Comment: How do you ensure that the two tables are compatible (have same fields)? Why do you copy values `AsString`? What about `Null` values then?

Comment: TDataSet already offers a method CopyFields for that.

Comment: @PeterWolf The 2 databases I have are exactly the same, they just have different names and purposes